# Nakayama's lemma, second version

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $J$ an ideal that is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$, and $A$ is finitely generated $R-$ module. If $R/J\otimes _R A=0$, then $A=0$.

====================================================================

Nakayama's lemma says that it is enough to show that $JA=A$.

Hungerford give two hints :

1. use the exact sequence $0\rightarrow J \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/J \rightarrow 0$
2. use the natural isomorphism $R\otimes _R A \cong A$

What I know is that $$ J\otimes _R A \rightarrow R\otimes _R A \rightarrow R/J \otimes _R A \rightarrow 0 $$ is exact sequence. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $R/J\otimes_R A=0$, the second exact sequence implies that the map 
$$J\otimes_R A\to R\otimes_R A\cong A$$
is surjective. $J\otimes_R A$ is generated by elements of the form $j\otimes a$ for some $a\in A$ and $j\in J$. The homomorphism $J\otimes_R A\to A\otimes_R R\cong A$ sends $j\otimes a\mapsto j\otimes a=ja$. The image is thus $JA$ (as $JA$ is the submodule generated by all such elements) and the map is surjective. Hence $JA=A$.

Comment: Why is $J \otimes_R A \to A$ injective? I think the statement you want is only that "the image of $J \otimes_R A$ in $A$ is $JA$."

Comment: (Relatedly, the equation $j \otimes a = 1 \otimes ja$ does not make sense in $J \otimes A$ since $1 \notin J$. It only makes sense after mapping to $R \otimes A$.)

Comment: @JakeLevinson Edited with regard to the second comment, thanks. I never say $J\otimes_R A\to A$ is injective though, just surjective.

Comment: No problem. Still, the fact remains that the map $J \otimes_R A \to R \otimes_R A$ is not necessarily an inclusion (specifically if $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(A,R/J) \ne 0$).